# Jquery appears to only read i as 0 from within a C# loop

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a Jquery handler set up so when a link within the for loop is clicked the Id is passed to a hidden form field, however whenever the link is clicked it always shows the first option from within the for loop.

C# (ASP .Net)

```
    @{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < GetComments.totalRows; i++)
    {
        <p class="comment-@GetComments.commentId[i]">
            @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(GetComments.body[i])) <br />
            <a href="#comment-@GetComments.commentId[i]" class="@i" id="replyTo">Reply to this comment</a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <br />
        </p>
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
   $('a#replyTo').on('click', function () {
                    $(".addNewComment form").css("visibility", "visible");
                  console.log(document.getElementById('replyTo').className);
          $('input[name="inReplyTo"]').val(document.getElementById('replyTo').className);
});
```

When I view the Browser Console no matter which link I click on I see 0 returned.

How can I set the class to load i rather than the first instance of i?

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**. Fix it and the problem is gone.

Comment: If I use GetComments.commentId[i] (Database Id - All Unique) for the class id's instead of i the issue still appears but only the first GetComments.commentId[i] is used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks andreas

I realise the replyTo needs to be unique not the class.

Sorry for my mistake.